# Avoiding NANs for expressions that are partly imaginary in c++

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I have an expression whose outcome is a real number, but is composed of imaginary terms (that cancel one another). A significantly more simple example than the one I am considering would be something like,

> *z = a + 1/[sqrt(a-b) - a] - f[sqrt(a-b)] = a*

where a and b are real numbers and f is some function that statisfies the above expression. It would not surprise you that in some cases, say for b > a (which does not always occur, but could occur in some cases), the above expression returns nan, since some of its terms are imaginary.

Sometimes, it is possible to work out the algebra and write out this not-really-complex expression using real numbers only. However, in my case, the algebra is very messy (so messy that even Matlab's symbolic package and Mathematica are unable to trivially simplify).

I am wondering if there is some other way to work out expressions you know to be real, but are partly imaginary.

---

PS: not important for this question, but for more info about the expression I am dealing with, please see [another question I previously asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3868980/height-of-spherical-cap-contained-inside-a-spherical-cap).

Comment: May be you should use complex numbers. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/complex

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I would if I could separate the real and imaginary terms. The algebra is just so bad, so I am looking for an easy(ier) way out. :-)

Comment: @liorr That's why `std::complex` can be very helpful. You don't need to separate out the real and imaginary terms. Instead, you just treat the number as a single complex number.

Comment: Just using complex numbers _is_ the easy way out. I don't understand what you think the obstacle is.

Comment: @Justin Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it wouldn't help in more complex (ha-ha) examples, right? Say, for example, you have an expression like 1 / (sqrt(x-y) + a*x) where x,y are real, but in some cases y > x. How would that work in that case?

Comment: @Useless Maybe I am misunderstanding the way this package works, but would it be able to separate complicated complex numbers, like in the example I gave in the above comment? How?

Comment: Read the reference Maxim posted. You perform your computation on `std::complex<double>` or whatever, and then examine the `real` and `imag` parts at the end. If `imag` is non-zero (or within some reasonable epsilon of zero), then it didn't cancel out. If `imag` _is_ zero, you have your `real` result.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Yeah, it could be that I don't know how to work out complex number after a PhD in physics (who knows anything about complex analysis, really?), but I think it is slightly more probable that I was just confused about how to use the package. I still doubt your suggestion would work in my case, but I'll give it a go as I'm willing to admit my cpp knowledge is lacking

Comment: `std::complex` is supposed to work more-or-less intuitively if you're used to complex numbers, which is why I assumed you weren't. It's just a pair of numbers after all, wouldn't it be weird if you _couldn't_ separate them?

Comment: I just think the example I gave is overly simplified. I should have been more elaborate. In the spirit of SO, I will edit my question with a better example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** for the comment thread:

If you know you're doing something that will involve imaginary numbers, just use [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/complex).

You can't avoid getting NaN if you insist on asking for a real result to something (`sqrt`, say) that you know will have an imaginary component. There *is* no real answer it can give you.

At the end of your computation, if `imag(result)` is zero (or within a suitable epsilon), then your imaginary parts cancelled out and you have a `real(result)`.

As a concrete example:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> a{-5, 0}; // -5 + 0i
    std::complex<double> b{ 5, 0}; // +5 + 0i
    auto z = b + sqrt(a) - sqrt(a);
    std::cout  << "z = " << real(z) << " + " << imag(z) << "i\n";
}
```

prints

```
z = 5 + 0i
```

---

With your new example

```
z = a + 1/(sqrt(a-b) - a) - f(sqrt(a-b)) = a
```

it'll be useful to make `a` of type `std::complex` in the first place, and to use a complex `1+0i` for the numerator as well. This is because of the way overloaded operators are resolved:

```
using cx = std::complex<double>;

cx f(cx); // whatever this does, it also needs to handle complex inputs

cx foo(cx a, cx b)
{
  return a + cx{1}/(sqrt(a-b) - a) - f(sqrt(a-b));
}
auto
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to accept the answer even though it did not work in my case, admitting my example was probably overly simplified.

Comment: You may need to make sure the left-hand-side of expressions are complex due to the way operator overloading works. Eg, `complex<double>{a} + complex<double>{1}/(...)`. And of course, any function `f` that isn't part of the standard math library needs to be written to take & return `std::complex`.

Comment: I actually take it back. My problem was different. I initialized the `std::complex <double> c` by doing `std::complex <double> c = sqrt(expression)`. However, this did not work, obviously, since `sqrt()` returns `double`, which means I received `c=(nan, 0)`. For it to work, I had to initialize `std::complex <double> c(0,0)`. Upvoted.